# How to solve this sql string in Dbutils ？

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, crud, apache-commons-dbutils

```
    public List<Hero> list() throws SQLException {
        return list(0, Short.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    public List<Hero> list(int start, int count) throws SQLException{

             Connection c = this.getConnection();                
             QueryRunner runner = new QueryRunner();
             String sql = "select * from hero order by id desc limit ?,? ";  
             Object params[] = {"start", "count" };                               
             List<Hero> heros = (List<Hero>) runner.query(c,sql,new BeanListHandler(Hero.class),params);     

             DbUtils.closeQuietly(c);    

             return heros;
    }
```

Before that I have imported Dbutils JAR that I need, like `org.apache.commons.dbutils.handlers.BeanListHandler`   and 
`org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner`
But after running my project, it goes wrongs whose message is :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''start','count'' at line 1 Query: select * from hero order by id
>   desc limit ?,? Parameters: [start, count]

I know that something wrong in program, but I dont want to find all, I just want to find part of my table using limit ?.? (I only know this sql sentence can do that).

Could u please help me?

Comment: You want to limit result just choose the number of returned row you want to return to b like limit 15;

Comment: u misunderstand my meaning .i wanna know how to solve this wrong to make this project run successfully. This is just a method which i can use in another class . haven u see the int start and int count?

Comment: OK, tell me what exactly you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing strings as your parameters, so it's running your SQL limit literally as `LIMIT 'start','count'`

Try this instead:

`Object params[] = {start, count };`

So that you're building a parameter array of your actual `int` values (now autoboxed to `Integer`)